# Example Sign-up/Sign in using node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket, cassandra

I'm new on using node.js
Surfing around the web i couldn't find any example of code of a simple sign-up/sign-in that could also show me how to manage database in node.

I mean the app.js page for server and the related client-side html page, and their relation. Can someone help me or give some useful link i couldn't find?

using Cassandra and i.o. socket, it'd be the best help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Passport library http://passportjs.org/ , there should be an example there. You can also use https://npmjs.org/package/passport.socketio if you want to login by socket.io

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using http://passportjs.org

It has support for simple username/password authentication as well as OAuth etc
http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

There's also a good tutorial here:
http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/